# Will there be no security updates for Windows Home Server 2011 after 12th April 2016?

Tags: windows, windows-home-server

For Windows 7 there will be extended support, but will there be one for WHS 2011? According to this [tool](http://support2.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/default.aspx?sort=PN&alpha=Windows+Home+Server+2011&Filter=FilterNO) there is none. Does this mean that there won't be any security updates anymore? So WHS 2011 is finally dead? I thought that because it is a server product it has a greater lifetime than Windows 7 for example.

Comment: Windows Home Server 2011 is based on Windows 2008R2, so try to install the 2008R2 updates.

Comment: I assume the naming is the same. Where do you get these updates for example? Directly from the Microsoft website?

Comment: Check first WindowsUpdate and if you can't see them there, look in the Microsoft downloadcenter: http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/default.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Home Server is a home product and unfortunately, it isn't covered by their extended support policy.

If there is no replacement product launched and enough users kick up a fuss, they may extend it - but, you can't count on anything beyond the official support lifecycle page you linked to.